# Using Cases with update in oracle query

Tags: oracle

How to use `CASE` of `WHEN` and `THEN` in oracle `UPDATE` query, I have tried as following but no success,

when user status_id in 1,3,5 update ID to 3 (**yes even if already 3 is there**), and when status is 2 update to 4.

```
UPDATE USER
CASE WHEN USER_STATUS_ID IN ('1','3','5') THEN SET USER_STATUS_ID='3' WHEN USER_STATUS_ID IN ('2') THEN SET USER_STATUS_ID='4',
BLOCKING_REASON_CODE=(SELECT REASON_CODE_ID FROM REASON_CODES WHERE REASON_CODE='AGE_LIMIT')
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IN 
(SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM CUSTOMER_AGE_TABLE) 
WHERE BATCH_ID=101
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your status is a `varchar`, even if it always seems to contain numbers, you may try:

```
update yourTable
set status_id = case
  when status_id in ('1','3','5')  then '3'
  when status_id = '2' then '4'
  else status_id             -- no changes if status is not in 1, 2, 3, 4
end
where ...
```

If it is a number, you can remove the `''`.

The `else` part is needed if you want to avoid `null`; for example:

```
select case when 1=2 then 'a' end from dual
```

gives `null`.

You may avoid it, by adding some more conditions in the `WHERE` clause, but this mainly depends on whether you always need to update that column, even if with no changes, or not.

Comment: Without the ELSE, the CASE will give null, so you'll update to null